# reusing same port in a tcp application under different namespaces on linux VM

Tags: linux, tcp, port-forwarding, namespace, network-namespaces

i have a linux VM with 2 interfaces, eth0 has mgmt IP and eth1 has configuration as below
ip netns exec eng51 ifconfig
eth1.51   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:bd:68:c3
          inet addr:51.51.1.10  Bcast:51.51.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

ip netns exec eng52 ifconfig
eth1.52   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:bd:68:c3
          inet addr:51.51.2.10  Bcast:51.51.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

ip netns exec eng522 ifconfig
eth1.522  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:bd:68:c3
          inet addr:51.51.2.10  Bcast:51.51.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

ip netns exec eng511 ifconfig
eth1.511  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:bd:68:c3
          inet addr:51.51.1.10  Bcast:51.51.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

So I have a script which uses tcp protocol and i need to simultaneously send traffic

from eng51[51.51.1.10 vlan-id 51] to eng52[ 51.51.2.10 vlan-id 52]
and i use same script to send traffic from eng52[ 51.51.1.10 vlan-id 511] to eng522 [51.51.2.10 vlan-id 522]

I run the script under name different namespaces:
ip netns exec eng51 python client.py 51.51.2.10
ip netns exec eng511 python client.py 51.51.2.10

inside client.py i bind the source port to be always 63999 and i have a HTTPserver running on port 8000 for both namespaces eng52 and eng522
     sock.bind(('0.0.0.0',63999))

the reason i am binding source port to 63999 is I need source-Address,destination,address,source port, destination port and protocol to be same 
in both traffic sessions

the problem I face is even though I run this script under different namespaces, the source port is not considered unique. I am unable to run the script under different namespaces at the same time[ due to usage of same port 63999]

Answer (score 0):

So I got this working by simply using multiple interfaces, mapping each interface of a VM to a namespace. And then I was able to use source port 63999 at the same time in 2 simultaneous sessions

ip netns eng51 ifconfig eth1.51 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 52:54:00:bd:68:c3 inet addr:51.51.1.10 Bcast:51.51.1.255 Mask:255.255.255.0

ip netns exec eng52 ifconfig eth2.52 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 52:54:00:bd:68:c3 inet addr:51.51.2.10 Bcast:51.51.2.255 Mask:255.255.255.0

ip netns exec eng522 ifconfig eth3.522 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 52:54:00:bd:68:c3 inet addr:51.51.2.10 Bcast:51.51.2.255 Mask:255.255.255.0

ip netns exec eng511 ifconfig eth4.511 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 52:54:00:bd:68:c3 inet addr:51.51.1.10 Bcast:51.51.1.255 Mask:255.255.255.0